# Battery died while transferring files

Tags: mount, kubuntu, hard-drive

my laptop's battery is very old and while I was transferring some important files on an external drive, it died on me. Unfortunately, this happened before I could transfer everything over.

When I booted back up, the folder I was transferring was greyed out, and I could not mount my external drive at all. In particular I got the error message "wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock ...".

Any ideas on what I am supposed to do now? Most important thing is to safely recover any files that might have gone missing during the transfer (I am manually checking on another machine right now).

Many thanks in advance.

p.s. I am not kubuntu with dolphin as my file manager, for all that matters.

Comment: Being specific with details is usually helpful. You mention Kubuntu, but not what release of Kubuntu, and what file-systems are you using. Given the power outage I'd expect your file-systems to be in an *unclean* state, thus fix with using the appropriate *file-system check* command for your *unstated* file-system. Kubuntu defaults to *ext4* thus `fsck`; but if using another *fs* use the appropriate command. If errors are detected (& fixed) by the command, I'd expect normal operation after that (*though the last file that was copied maybe incomplete on destination, so I'd delete it*)

Comment: Use disks or gparted to perform a file system check on that drive - I’d be reasonably hopeful you’ll get most of your data back. But please learn that (1) it’s always sensible to plug your laptop in when doing things like this, especially if the battery is old; but critically (2) you really must not rely on an external drive as the only place to store important data, and (3) when transferring files, it’s safer to copy them to the destination, then when you know they are safely copied, delete the original - than to cut and paste or move the files in one manoeuvre.